# How to format a phone number in AMPscript

Tags: salesforce1-app, marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'd like to re-format a phone number in AMPscript from 1234567890 to (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890. I've tried using the Format function

```
%%=Format(%%CLIENT_PHONE%%,"(###) ###-####")=%%
```

where CLIENT_PHONE evaluates to 1234567890.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question here - sorry for that - looks like I added too many % signs.

`%%=Format(CLIENT_PHONE,"(###) ###-####")=%%`

That corrected the issue, and it now works perfectly. Thanks all!

Comment: Hi Kelly, thanks for posting the answer. This helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with AMPscript, but looking at the documentation, it appears that it uses C# syntax. Try

```
%%=Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", %%CLIENT_PHONE%%)=%%
```

Comment: Thank you - it turns out the syntax I had was correct, but I added too many percent signs. `%%=Format(CLIENT_PHONE,"(###) ###-####")=%%` would do the trick.